# Como funciona o settimeout('__dopostback( 'dropdownlist 1 ' ' ')' 0)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

eu gostaria de saber como que funciona, pois estou tentando aprender, e estou com algumas dúvidas, sou iniciante nesse assunto estou lendo sobre javascript há poucos dias.

Eu gostaria de saber como funciona também o tabindex.

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre o `setTimeout`, ou sobre o `doPostBack` que tem dentro? Quanto ao tabindex, melhor postar uma pergunta separada sobre isso (aqui no site nós tentamos separar as perguntas assim por tema para que depois elas possam ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida).

Comment: java != javascript

Answer (score 0):

Na prática eu utilizo para setar um evento server side via JavaScript.
Detalhes:

- settimeout: Seta um tempo de espera para executar uma função ou ação.
- dopostback: Chama a função de postback, passando com parâmetro o elemento do evento.